# Include image in notification

Tags: image, notifications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am currently trying to convert a Chrome extension to Firefox. The original Chrome extension involves a notification of the type `"image"`. The code is a follows:

```
chrome.notifications.create({
    type: "image",
    iconUrl: "image/logo.jpg",
    imageUrl: "image/testimage.jpg",
    title: "Test",
    message: "Test message"
 });
```

Now, when converting this notification to Firefox by changing the `chrome.` to `browser.`, the notification pops up nicely - although without the image. From the MDN sites, I get the vague impression that this feature is not (yet) included in the Firefox Notification API. Can anybody tell me if this is the case (and if yes, whether the feature will be implemented soonish)? Or am I doing something wrong? And is there any other way to implement image notifications in Firefox?

Comment: You do not need to change your API calls from `chrome.*` to `browser.*` for things to work in Firefox. All of the WebExtension APIs work as both [`chrome.*` *and* `browser.*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#Callbacks_and_the_chrome.*_namespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only [type of notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/TemplateType) that [Firefox supports is the `'basic'` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/TemplateType#Compatibility_notes). For an image, the `'basic'` type supports an [optional `iconUrl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/NotificationOptions#iconUrl).

When other types of [Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications) will be implemented in Firefox is unclear. Until something is actually in the process of being implemented, or at least further in the process than it is currently, there is no good way to tell exactly when it will happen. Although, [filing a bug requesting the functionality](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) will make it easier to track when it is happening.

> And is there any other way to implement image notifications in Firefox?

Officially, no. If you really wanted to, you could open a window [`windows.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create) to a URL inside your extension which displays the desired image.

### What you can do to make it happen sooner

- [File a bug in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) requesting this specific feature.
- Implement the functionality yourself.  Firefox is an open source project to which you can contribute. WebExtensions APIs are primarily written in JavaScript. The Notifications API can be found within the [code for WebExtensions](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/extensions) beginning in the [*ext-notifications.js*](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/extensions/ext-notifications.js) and [*notifications.json*](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/extensions/schemas/notifications.json) files.

### Changing from `chrome.*` to `browser.*` is not required

You do not need to change your API calls from chrome.* to browser.* for things to work in Firefox. All of the WebExtension APIs work as both [`chrome.*` and `browser.*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#Callbacks_and_the_chrome.%2A_namespace). The `chrome.*` namespace works with callbacks, just as it does in Chrome (with minor, mostly documented incompatibilities, as listed on each [JavaScript API page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs)). The `browser.*` namespace works with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Makyen. Sad to hear that the image notification does not work yet. But good to hear that it was not because if a mistake of mine that it does not work :-)